Fixing Error: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null) by double checking package name
I'm using Flutter for the front end and this error
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
surfaced when I was trying to integrate the google sign available through firebase using the google_sign_in package in flutter. I figured out the solution but I was unable to comment as I do not have enough reputation
What helped me solve the issue is that when we are using Firebase CLI for configuring firebase in our flutter apps, we come across the package name and maybe not pay enough attention to that. When the package name given in the configuration is different from the package name in the firebase console (which I think is more likely happening to those who use the firebase_cli to configure firebase with flutter), this error can come.
package name in firebase console
package name in android/app/build.gradle
Try this if all the common methods like adding the SHA-1 keys, adding the contact email etc fails.
I solved the issue by doing the above, the answers in the original thread did not help me solve the issue, I also found others not able to figure out the solution. This lead to me creating this new thread.
